# Flutter archive plugin Dart for loop end condition

Tags: dart

Using DART, I have a for loop like so:

```
 void fl(){
    for(final file in archive){
        print(file.name);
    }
 }
```

How can the for loop let me know when it is completed? For example, I want to run a function after the loop completes.

```
 void fl(){
    for(final file in archive){
        print(file.name);
    }
    //forloop done
    //do function();
 }
```

Using a standard `for(i=0;i<archive.length();i++)` idea, I can examine i to be -1 the length of the archive.length, but for the `final file in archive` version I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

The following type of for-loop can also be called a foreach loop and can be used on objects which implements Iterable:

```
    for(final file in archive){
        print(file.name);
    }
```

Iterable means we ask the class to be accessed sequentially and so we can go though each element automatically by using the foreach notation instead of using the traditionally for-loop with a counter.

For each element processed in the foreach-loop the `final file` variable will be set to a value of the `archive`. In you example it will mean that we ends up printing the filename of each file in the archive.

When all elements in the archive objects has been processed the foreach loop will stop and you will automatically continue executing the code after the loop. So the following code will work as expected:

```
 void fl(){
    for(final file in archive){
        print(file.name);
    }
    //forloop done
    //do function();
 }
```

I am therefore not sure want you problem really are? If you want, you can actually use the traditionally for-loop for objects of the Archive class since the Archive both implements `[]` and `length` [1]:

```
 void fl(){
    for(var i = 0; i < archive.length; i++){
        print(archive[i].name);
    }
    //forloop done
    //do function();
 }
```

[1] https://github.com/brendan-duncan/archive/blob/master/lib/src/archive.dart

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am asking for a foreach().then() type of thing for the foreach loop in dart. ie... we know when archive.length is 0, but without the var i, to keep track, we don't know this. It sounds like there isn't such a feature or I am not explaining it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are talking about. If you think it is simpler I have given you an example showing how to get a counter variable.